# how to retrieve data from db and display it in two tables or more in php?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to display data from database into multi table in html. here is my code:

php code:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("gestion_condidat");
$requet1 ="SELECT * FROM spe_tab WHERE langue ='ar'";
   if($res = mysql_query($requet1)){
       if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo'<img src="images/linep.png"><br>';     /*succisful*/
            echo'<CAPTION ALIGN=top><h2><span style="color: #EFB61A">|</span>'.$row['type'].'<span style="color: #EFB61A">|</span></h2></CAPTION> ';
            echo'<table id="customers">';
            echo' <tr><th> <center> الاختـــصـــاص</center></th><th><center>شروط الالتــحـاق</center></th><th><center>الشهــادة المحصــلة</center></th></tr>';
            echo '<tr class="spe">';
            echo '<td>'.$row['nom'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['cond'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['diplome'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr  style="display:none"><td colspan="3">'.$row['info'].'</td></tr>';
            echo'</table> <br><br>';
            }
  }}
  else {
     echo" Il ya une erreur ! <br><br>".mysql_error();     /*error*/
  }
?>
```

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="admin2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br><img src="images/linep.png"><br>
<br>
<h2 style="color: #AF7AC5">اضافة تخصص جديد</h2><br>
<div class="cad-1 cad-2 cad-3 cad-4 cad-5 cad-7 cad-10 cad-12">

<span style="float: right">الدورة</span>
<input type="text" class="form-controlmine" name="type" placeholder="مثال: أمن صناعي" required="">

<br><br><span style="float: right">الإختصاص</span>
<input type="text" class="form-controlmine" name="nom" placeholder="مثال: اسعافات أولية" required="">

<br><br><span style="float: right">شروط الإلتحاق</span>
<input type="text" class="form-controlmine" name="cond" placeholder="مثال: جامعي" required="">

<br><br><span style="float: right">الشهادة المحصلة</span>
<input type="text" class="form-controlmine" name="diplome" placeholder="مثال: شهادة تأهيلية" required="">

<br><br><span style="float: right">معلومات إضافية</span>
<input type="text" class="form-controlmine" name="info" placeholder="" required="">

<br><br><input type="submit" name="add" value="إضافة">
</div>


</form>
```

I have php and html in one page.

I have to create new table every time the `$row['type']` changed.

It means that each table will display with the same name of `$row['type']` ,but has different parameters `$row['nom'], $row['cond'], $row['diplome'], $row['info']`

can i duplicate `mysql_fetch_array` or what should i do ??
Can you please show how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem ... 
this is the solution ...it is complicated but it work
code php:

````
mysql_select_db("gestion_condidat");
$requet1 ="SELECT * FROM spe_tab WHERE langue ='ar' ORDER BY type ASC ";
   if(($res = mysql_query($requet1))&&($ref = mysql_query($requet1))){
       if ((mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)&&(mysql_num_rows($ref) > 0)) {
         $new = mysql_fetch_array($ref);
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $row=$new;
            if(($row!=null)&&($new!=null)){
            echo'<img src="images/linep.png"><br>';
            echo'<CAPTION ALIGN=top><h2><span style="color: #EFB61A">|</span>'.$row['type'].'<span style="color: #EFB61A">|</span></h2></CAPTION> ';
            echo'<table id="customers">';
            echo' <tr><th> <center> الاختـــصـــاص</center></th><th><center>شروط الالتــحـاق</center></th><th><center>الشهــادة المحصــلة</center></th></tr>';
            while($row['type']==$new['type']){
              echo '<tr class="spe">';
              echo '<td>'.$new['nom'].'</td>';
              echo '<td>'.$new['cond'].'</td>';
              echo '<td>'.$new['diplome'].'</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
              echo '<tr  style="display:none"><td colspan="3">'.$new['info'].'</td></tr>';
              $new = mysql_fetch_array($ref);
            }
            echo'</table> <br><br>';
  }}
  }}
  else {
     echo" Il ya une erreur ! <br><br>".mysql_error();     /*error*/
  }
?>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You will need an `ORDER BY type` in the sql so you can detect when `$row['type']` changes.

What would you need to do on such a change? You would have to close the previous `<table>` *if there is one* (remember, there would not  be an open `<table>` element when the first row is processed). Then start a new `<table>`. (Similarly remember to echo the final `</table>` when the loop is complete.)

Beware, `id` should be unique so this `echo'<table id="customers">';` would be problematic.

You'll probably need a couple of new variables: one to keep track of the current type, one to know if this is the first row. You should be able to incorporate this "break" logic within the existing `while` loop.

Comment: thank you very mutch ... it works ... I added  `ORDER BY type` and i duplicated run of my requet sql for make condition in loop...                                                                               I take a complicated solution, but it worked....